# Explanation for random ClassNotFoundExceptions?

Tags: android

I have an app with ~11k active installs for which I sometimes receive ClassNotFoundExceptions that I can't explain. They look like this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{name.of.my.MainActivityClass}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: name.of.my.MainActivityClass in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/mnt/asec/name.of.my-2/pkg.apk]
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1743)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1851)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1038)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4293)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: name.of.my.MainActivityClass in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/mnt/asec/name.of.my-2/pkg.apk]
at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1040)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1735)
... 11 more
```

I received some of these exceptions from users that updated my app (not only for the most recent version), so I think it is not a problem that is specific to some phones as the app worked for them before.
I got these exception reports for my main activity class, a receiver class and a BackupAgent class.
All of those classes are always instantiated directly from Android. My Manifest file looks like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="name.of.my"
      android:versionCode="20"
      android:versionName="1.10.2"
      android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:backupAgent="name.of.my.OwnBackupAgent">
        <activity android:name="name.of.my.MainActivityClass"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="name.of.my.OwnReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.media.RINGER_MODE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

After searching the net for some hours, the most likely explanations I found are:

- it might be related to moving the app to SD card while there are still some services running (but the android dev guide says that all services are canceled in this case, and it doesn't explain why my main activity class suddenly can't be found anymore)
- the .apk might be corrupted after updating via the android market. Could this be true? If yes, what can I do against it - if not, what else might be the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure what code, since it affects multiple classes. Also note that my main activity and the BackupAgent are only referenced in my manifest file and are always called directly from Android, not from my own code.
Is there anything particular you want to see?

Comment: ya post your manifest file then.

Comment: Posted the interesting part, just left out the other activities and permissions. I double-checked, and the receiver is also always instantiated directly from Android.

Comment: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{name.of.my.MainActivityClass}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: name.of.my.MainActivityClass in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/mnt/asec/name.of.my-2/pkg.apk]` this line gives u the hint, the system is tryng to find the earlier non updated classes , from the new updated apk version (apk-2).. happens often in the emulator when u run ur activity many times

Comment: I've seen this on 10+ app's I've realeased to the market/others have released. Don't worry, just Android error you can't controle